# Convert [Float] to variables arguments

Tags: swift, variables, arguments, nsstring

I'm trying to use `NSString(format: , arg...)` to update a UILabel by incrementing one or more values in this label.

To do that, I have a function where I am receiving the args as `Float...` (which is what I want) and the only solution I found to store them is by using an array `[Float]` (which is not what I want).
Then, I'm modifying each value of my array to display it.

To modify the text of my UILabel, I am using `label.text = NSString(format: "%f and %f", myArrayOfFloat)` and it does not work. NSString takes the array as a single value, not as an array.

If anyone has a solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a

```
NSString(format: String, arguments argList: CVaListPointer)
```

initializer which takes the substitution values as a `CVaListPointer`
(which is the Swift equivalent of `va_list` in C). Example:

```
let myArrayOfFloat: [Float] = [1.2, 3.4]
let text = withVaList(myArrayOfFloat) {
    NSString(format: "%f and %f", arguments: $0)
}
print(text) // 1.200000 and 3.400000
```

However, it is simpler to create a  `String`, using the

```
String(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg])
```

initializer, which takes the substitution values as a single array parameter. Example:

```
let myArrayOfFloat: [Float] = [1.2, 3.4]
let text = String(format: "%f and %f", arguments: myArrayOfFloat)
print(text) // 1.200000 and 3.400000
```

Comment: Yeeeesssss, that's exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you ;)